# Detecting current culture for Serbia

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization

I have a method that does some specific processing depending on the name of the current culture. Now, normally I build up that name using

```
cultureName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName +
              "-" +
              System.Globalization.RegionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName;
```

This works in cases like en-AU or tr-TR; however, Serbia is a special case in that its culture names have an additional part (e.g., sr-Latn-RS or sr-Cyrl-RS). Is there a way for me to discover the middle part? I don't see any property in the CultureInfo class returning that.

Comment: A quick google search will provide you with [this](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/).

Comment: ... and a hundred similar pages (I've been Googling for two days). I am asking for a way to build the name *in code*: given that the code runs on a Serbian machine, how can I build the string sr-Latn-RS or sr-Cyrl-RS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this should do the trick:

```
cultureName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
```

The [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.name.aspx) property returns exactly what you need, but if you want, you can extract the 3 different parts, if you Split the string by the '`-`' character.

Comment: Wow... I cannot believe I missed that - I looked at DisplayName and NativeName but not at Name. Today was not a good day for me.